# import excel as an document library

Tags: document-library, excel

Is there a way to import excel as an document library just like custom list > import spreadsheet?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The only option is to Upload the file, list and document libraries are different in form and function.  You can use the single file uploader, the multiple file uploader, or the Open with Windows Explorer function in the Actions menu.

You can create a document content type and attach an Excel templte to it so that new Excel files created in the document library have the same template.